# Loop through custom list items in sharepoint 2010 designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using sharepoint 2010 designer and my requirement is as follows:

I have a document library for which i have configured an email id (i will now refer to it as "Email Library") and it will be receiving emails.

i have to display the emails in a web part but i should have a filter that only  emails of certain categories can be displayed. i have the categories separately in another list called "Email Category".

Now i want to check if each of the emails belong to any of the categories while it is being added to the email library, based on the name of the email(if the email name contains any of the categories listed in Email Category list, then i can populate a column isCategorised=="Y" and later while displaying, filter with the same).

I wanted to achieve this with sharepoint designer 2010 workflow(i have got only 2010, our project is not yet upgraded to 2013 - i heard looping option is there in 2013)

The workflow goes like this

*if CurrentItem : Name Contains Email Category:Title,
update item in CurrentItem*

But while setting the lookup in Email Category:Title, it gave the warning "The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return single value. If more than value is returned only the first value will be used"

Pretty much clear i can't check against all the items in list.

I need to have the emails Categorised while they are added in the email library.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: How many categories do you have, and how often do they change?

Comment: I can't be sure of that now, it could be a smaller number like 10 now but new items will be added in future

Comment: I suppose you could add an explicit action for each category, but that won't be much fun to maintain in the long term.